# select data and take a mean based on date and time span from another dataframe

Tags: r

I have a problem. So, I have two dataframes, one in which I have the date and time in which I took a certain measurement. The measurement time is one hour. Based on that date and time I want to take the mean of the `VPD` column from another dataframe in that timespan. Means I need to take the means of the `VPD` column, starting at the `time` of dataframe `test` and ending after one hour. That mean `VPD` I then want to add to the `test`dataframe. Another problem is that the first dataframe uses 5 minutes steps, while the second one uses 10 minutes step.

This is the dataframe which contains the information about my measurements:

```
test <- structure(list(treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), plot = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(19028, 19028, 
 19033, 19035, 19038, 19033, 19046, 19046, 19035, 19038), class = "Date"), 
 time = c("11:05:00", "14:20:00", "13:20:00", "12:40:00", 
"10:55:00", "10:45:00", "14:45:00", "12:30:00", "10:45:00", 
"13:25:00")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

And this dataframe contains weatherdata in 10 minutes steps:

```
test2 <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1644055200, 1644055800, 
 1644056400, 1644057000, 1644057600, 1644058200, 1644058800, 1644059400, 
 1644060000, 1644060600, 1644061200, 1644061800, 1644062400, 1644063000, 
 1644063600, 1644064200, 1644064800, 1644065400, 1644066000, 1644066600, 
 1644067200, 1644067800, 1644068400, 1644069000, 1644069600, 1644070200, 
 1644070800, 1644071400, 1644072000, 1644072600, 1644073200, 1644073800, 
 1644074400, 1644075000, 1644075600, 1644076200, 1644076800, 1644077400, 
 1644078000, 1644078600, 1644079200, 1644079800, 1644080400, 1644081000, 
 1644081600, 1644082200, 1644082800, 1644083400, 1644084000), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), VPD = c(2.02, 2.02, 2.16, 2.18, 2.17, 
 2.17, 2.29, 2.35, 2.35, 2.43, 2.53, 2.69, 2.8, 2.98, 3.34, 3.66, 
 3.73, 3.74, 3.2, 3.25, 3.29, 3.27, 3.24, 3.28, 3.29, 3.31, 3.6, 
 3.74, 3.62, 3.38, 3.22, 3.15, 3.16, 3.11, 3.14, 3, 2.94, 3.02, 
 2.97, 3.01, 2.89, 2.79, 2.83, 2.85, 2.91, 2.94, 2.84, 2.87, 2.75
)), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = "data.frame")
```

If anyone has an idea how to handle this I would be really grateful!

*EDITED* - changed test2 dataframe

Comment: The first observation of `test` starts at 11:05.  Which period do you want that to match in `test2`?  It could be that any one of  11:00-12:00, 11:10-12:10, or 11:10-12:00 might be reasonable.

Comment: I would round down and start from 11:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test2` data and `test` data don't match up in terms of time (`test` has observations from 2022 and `test2` from 2005), but assuming there are corresponding entries in both data frames, you should be able to do something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
test <- test %>% 
  mutate(date_time = ymd_hms(paste(as.character(date), time)))

test$meanVPD <- sapply(test$date_time, function(t){
  mins <- gsub(".*:(\\d{2}):00$", "\\1", as.character(t))
  if(grepl("5$", mins)){
    t <- t-minutes(5)
  }
  test2 %>% 
    filter(datetime >= t & datetime <= t+hours(1)) %>% 
    select(VPD) %>% 
    pull %>% 
    mean
}
```

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I had an conversion error and corrected the dates from ```test2``` now. Unfortunately this answer does not work for me, it tells me a bracket is missing but I can't find the right place to close it

Comment: Ok, just had to add the closing bracket at the end, now it worked! Thank you very much Dave! :)